# INSPIRE Regulations and "timeliness"

Tags: inspire, government

Firstly, I hope I'm not asking too general a question.

I'm being told by one of our public agencies that I can't be given permission to republish a dataset for protected areas in a simple format, such as GeoJSON. Given that they only make these available as SHP downloads (no online viewer either), it would be quite simple and helpful to enable this, for non-commercial purposes of course.

But republishing is forbidden! The reason, I'm told after requesting permission, is that the timeliness of the datasets might be compromised as they are updated on an irregular (though quite infrequent) basis.

Has anyone had any experience with this? Do you think it falls foul of INSPIRE regulations (specifically Article 13) given that their lack of a service allowing for easy viewing of the protected areas is a restriction on the use of (and potentially access to) the data?

Comment: I do not believe that GeoJSON has anything to do with this. It is a matter of principle. They consider that if someone else is republishing the data the publisher may not take care of updates and continue to deliver out-of-date contents. Some other countries follow an open data way - republish if you wish, perhaps with a requirement to mention where the original data comes and the date of the extract. Inspire requires that view and download services exist but directive does not require publishing data as open data.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I wanted to know, if INSPIRE had a requirement to allow this. It's not so clear. The problem is that they may have the download SHP options, but still no online viewer for these protected areas.

Comment: The INSPIRE directives only apply to certain public bodies and agencies.  Data supplied under the directives does not need to be open or free, you'll need to look at the metadata for the data/services concerned to see whether the data provider has any access and use restrictions.

Comment: Whilst GeoJSON is a nice way to hold data for web applications, it is by no means perfect.  The spec tells us for instance _The default reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates SHALL be ...  "http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84" ...
Other coordinate reference systems, including ones described by CRS objects of the kind defined in [GJ2008] are NOT RECOMMENDED._  The data providers may have an objection to you using GeoJSOn for this reason

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this has nothing to do with any INSPIRE regulations.  INSPIRE is (1) about publishing metadata for all data that a public organization curates, including information about how to access those data sets.

There is no requirement under INSPIRE for the data to be freely available, but the data sets you mention seem to be freely available because you say you can get the data as a shapefile.

INSPIRE is also about providing (2) view access and (3) providing downloads of data.

If you are an organization that comes under the INSPIRE regulations then the data and services you provide (through a paywall if required), must be supplied using a projection using the datum of the European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 (ETRS89), so strictly speaking that excludes publishing the data as GeoJSON; but again as you are not an an organization that comes under the INSPIRE regulations...